# Find the total time taken by each `id` within a 1 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find the total time taken by each `id`.

- There must be one activity within an hour (After the start of the one activity),
- and if there is any activity before the 1hrs time is elapsed, consider that time in the previous slot, calculate the time differences.
- if 1 hrs has already passed now check if there is any other activity within a 1hrs period

Sample data is:

```
create table test (
  id integer not null,
  ts datetime not null
);

insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:00');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:01');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:06');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:30');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 09:35');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-02 16:10');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-02 16:20');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-03 06:40');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-03 06:41');
insert into test values (2, '2012-01-01 08:30');
insert into test values (2, '2012-01-01 09:26');
insert into test values (2, '2012-01-01 10:25');
```

The output column will be:

```
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:00');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:01');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:06');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:30');
```

Here the differences are exactly: **00:30:00**

and there is the record which but it is after 1 hr, so we didn't add this activity on the previous slot and there is no activity up to 1 hour from this time so we do not consider this activity

```
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 09:35');`
```

Now, this runs for: **00:10:00**

```
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-02 16:10');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-02 16:20');
```

Similarly, this runs for **00:01:00**

```
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-03 06:40');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-03 06:41');
```

So the total time for `id=1` will be `00:41:00`.

```
id | Time duration (hh:mm:ss)
 1 | 00:41:00
 2 | 01:55:00
```

I couldn't think of how to start with this problem, any possible head-start would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) I don't understand the rules.  Can you be more explicit on how the final duration relate to the original records?

Comment: Should the 1 hour be considered from the time when the query is run or based on any of the records in the data?

Comment: any of the records..it should check to the subsequent rows to calculate the differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rules are a bit hard to follow, but I think I understand them.  Count the gap between two rows for the same id if the second is less than an hour after the first.  Then aggregate by the id.

So:

```
select id, sum(datediff(minute, ts, next_ts)) as duration_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lead(ts) over (partition by id order by ts) as next_ts
      from test t
     ) t
where datediff(minute, ts, next_ts) < 60
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=907b8b0a10e1d5eacf4b0fa134d3a1e2) is a db<>fiddle.

I am reluctant to convert the duration to a time value, because that is limited to just 24 hours.